# failed to create animation with flutter animator package

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I created a flutter project with the flutter_animator package: ^3.2.0
but i get an error while running the app which confuses me. I've made according to the documentation but still can't run. I also tried to use the animate_do package and the same error appears when run. this is my code:

```
import 'package:ayo_masak/utils/importutils.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_animator/flutter_animator.dart';
import 'package:get/get.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GetMaterialApp(
      title: 'Ayo Masak',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: AppThemeData.lightTheme,
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  GlobalKey<CrossFadeABState> crossFadeAnimation =
      GlobalKey<CrossFadeABState>();
  GlobalKey<AnimatorWidgetState> basicAnimation =
      GlobalKey<AnimatorWidgetState>();
  GlobalKey<InOutAnimationState> inOutAnimation =
      GlobalKey<InOutAnimationState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Flutter Animator'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20)),
            CrossFadeAB(
              key: crossFadeAnimation,
              childA: const Text('A', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
              childB: const Text('B', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
            ),
            const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20)),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                crossFadeAnimation.currentState!.cross();
              },
              child: const Text(
                'Cross Animate',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
              ),
            ),
            BounceIn(
              key: basicAnimation,
              child: const Text(
                'BounceIn',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
              ),
            ),
            const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20)),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                basicAnimation.currentState!.forward();
              },
              child: const Text(
                'Animate Bounce',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
              ),
            ),
            const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 40)),
            InOutAnimation(
              key: inOutAnimation,
              child: const Text(
                'In & Out',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
              ),
              inDefinition: FadeInAnimation(),
              outDefinition: BounceOutDownAnimation(),
            ),
            const Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20)),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                if (inOutAnimation.currentState!.status !=
                    InOutAnimationStatus.Out) {
                  inOutAnimation.currentState!.animateOut();
                } else {
                  inOutAnimation.currentState!.animateIn();
                }
              },
              child: const Text(
                'Animate In & Out',
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

and this is the log I get when after I run the application, there are many errors.
the strange thing is that in my code there is no error detected at all.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on ASUS X00RD in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_animator-3.2.0/lib/widgets/animator_widget.dart:85:16: Error: The getter 'definition' isn't defined for the class 'T Function()'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'definition'.
    if (widget.definition.needsWidgetSize && widgetSize == null) {
               ^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_animator-3.2.0/lib/widgets/animator_widget.dart:87:25: Error: The getter 'definition' isn't defined for the class 'T Function()'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'definition'.
        opacity: widget.definition.preRenderOpacity,
                        ^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_animator-3.2.0/lib/widgets/animator_widget.dart:88:23: Error: The getter 'child' isn't defined for the class 'T Function()'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'child'.
        child: widget.child,
                      ^^^^^
../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_animator-3.2.0/lib/widgets/animator_widget.dart:91:16: Error: The getter 'definition' isn't defined for the class 'T Function()'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'definition'.
    if (widget.definition.needsScreenSize && screenSize == null) {
               ^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_animator-3.2.0/lib/widgets/animator_widget.dart:93:25: Error: The getter 'definition' isn't defined for the class 'T Function()'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'definition'.
        opacity: widget.definition.preRenderOpacity,
                        ^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_animator-3.2.0/lib/widgets/animator_widget.dart:94:23: Error: The getter 'child' isn't defined for the class 'T Function()'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'child'.
        child: widget.child,
                      ^^^^^
../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_animator-3.2.0/lib/widgets/animator_widget.dart:97:44: Error: The getter 'child' isn't defined for the class 'T Function()'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'child'.
    return animator!.build(context, widget.child);
                                           ^^^^^
../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_animator-3.2.0/lib/widgets/animator_widget.dart:102:45: Error: The getter 'definition' isn't defined for the class 'T Function()'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'definition'.
    animator!.setAnimationDefinition(widget.definition);
                                            ^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_animator-3.2.0/lib/widgets/animator_widget.dart:103:16: Error: The getter 'definition' isn't defined for the class 'T Function()'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'definition'.
    if (widget.definition.needsWidgetSize ||
               ^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_animator-3.2.0/lib/widgets/animator_widget.dart:104:16: Error: The getter 'definition' isn't defined for the class 'T Function()'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'definition'.
        widget.definition.needsScreenSize) {
               ^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_animator-3.2.0/lib/widgets/animator_widget.dart:111:22: Error: The getter 'definition' isn't defined for the class 'T Function()'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'definition'.
          if (widget.definition.needsWidgetSize) {
                     ^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_animator-3.2.0/lib/widgets/animator_widget.dart:115:22: Error: The getter 'definition' isn't defined for the class 'T Function()'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'definition'.
          if (widget.definition.needsScreenSize) {
                     ^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_animator-3.2.0/lib/widgets/animator_widget.dart:123:32: Error: The getter 'definition' isn't defined for the class 'T Function()'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'definition'.
        handlePlayState(widget.definition.preferences.autoPlay);
                               ^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_animator-3.2.0/lib/widgets/animator_widget.dart:130:30: Error: The getter 'definition' isn't defined for the class 'T Function()'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'definition'.
      handlePlayState(widget.definition.preferences.autoPlay);
                             ^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_animator-3.2.0/lib/widgets/in_out_animation.dart:38:21: Error: The getter 'autoPlay' isn't defined for the class 'InOutAnimation Function()'.
 - 'InOutAnimation' is from 'package:flutter_animator/widgets/in_out_animation.dart' ('../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_animator-3.2.0/lib/widgets/in_out_animation.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'autoPlay'.
    status = widget.autoPlay;
                    ^^^^^^^^
../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_animator-3.2.0/lib/widgets/in_out_animation.dart:60:30: Error: The getter 'inDefinition' isn't defined for the class 'InOutAnimation Function()'.
 - 'InOutAnimation' is from 'package:flutter_animator/widgets/in_out_animation.dart' ('../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_animator-3.2.0/lib/widgets/in_out_animation.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'inDefinition'.
          definition: widget.inDefinition,
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_animator-3.2.0/lib/widgets/in_out_animation.dart:61:25: Error: The getter 'child' isn't defined for the class 'InOutAnimation Function()'.
 - 'InOutAnimation' is from 'package:flutter_animator/widgets/in_out_animation.dart' ('../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_animator-3.2.0/lib/widgets/in_out_animation.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'child'.
          child: widget.child,
                        ^^^^^
../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_animator-3.2.0/lib/widgets/in_out_animation.dart:66:30: Error: The getter 'outDefinition' isn't defined for the class 'InOutAnimation Function()'.
 - 'InOutAnimation' is from 'package:flutter_animator/widgets/in_out_animation.dart' ('../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_animator-3.2.0/lib/widgets/in_out_animation.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'outDefinition'.
          definition: widget.outDefinition,
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_animator-3.2.0/lib/widgets/in_out_animation.dart:67:25: Error: The getter 'child' isn't defined for the class 'InOutAnimation Function()'.
 - 'InOutAnimation' is from 'package:flutter_animator/widgets/in_out_animation.dart' ('../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_animator-3.2.0/lib/widgets/in_out_animation.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'child'.
          child: widget.child,
                        ^^^^^
../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_animator-3.2.0/lib/widgets/in_out_animation.dart:70:23: Error: The getter 'child' isn't defined for the class 'InOutAnimation Function()'.
 - 'InOutAnimation' is from 'package:flutter_animator/widgets/in_out_animation.dart' ('../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_animator-3.2.0/lib/widgets/in_out_animation.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'child'.
        return widget.child;
                      ^^^^^
../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_animator-3.2.0/lib/widgets/specials/cross_fade_a_b.dart:55:22: Error: The getter 'childA' isn't defined for the class 'CrossFadeAB Function()'.
 - 'CrossFadeAB' is from 'package:flutter_animator/widgets/specials/cross_fade_a_b.dart' ('../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_animator-3.2.0/lib/widgets/specials/cross_fade_a_b.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'childA'.
            ? widget.childA
                     ^^^^^^
../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_animator-3.2.0/lib/widgets/specials/cross_fade_a_b.dart:56:48: Error: The getter 'childA' isn't defined for the class 'CrossFadeAB Function()'.
 - 'CrossFadeAB' is from 'package:flutter_animator/widgets/specials/cross_fade_a_b.dart' ('../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_animator-3.2.0/lib/widgets/specials/cross_fade_a_b.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'childA'.
            : animatorA!.build(context, widget.childA),
                                               ^^^^^^
../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_animator-3.2.0/lib/widgets/specials/cross_fade_a_b.dart:57:65: Error: The getter 'childB' isn't defined for the class 'CrossFadeAB Function()'.
 - 'CrossFadeAB' is from 'package:flutter_animator/widgets/specials/cross_fade_a_b.dart' ('../../../Development/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/flutter_animator-3.2.0/lib/widgets/specials/cross_fade_a_b.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'childB'.
        if (animatorB != null) animatorB!.build(context, widget.childB),
                                                                ^^^^^^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/macbook pro/Documents/Development/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 1005

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command '/Users/macbook pro/Documents/Development/flutter/bin/flutter'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 26s
```

Comment: which line is it telling about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I succeeded by deleting my flutter sdk and re-downloading the flutter sdk, and finally the animation can run.
somehow with the previous flutter sdk.